# Code under volley response not firing

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have this basic example, but the problem is that Anything I write under the volley on response is not firing even a Toast. Below is my code.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.10.1/holycare/install.php";
private Button mGetJsonButton;
RequestQueue requestQueue;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    mGetJsonButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_json_btn);
    mGetJsonButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, jsonObject.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }


    });


}
```

}

My back end code, the URL is pointing to has no problem as it returns a json response. The code in the JsonException catch part is rather giving the response. That is strange.

```
[
   {
       "id": "1",
       "title": "Welcome to 2017",
       "date_created": "2017-02-17 11:04:12",
       "body": "Hello to all staff of Holy Medical Center, We welcome you all to 2017. Wishing you all a properous New year"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Special Announcement",
    "date_created": "2017-02-17 11:15:50",
    "body": "All National Service Persons are expected to meet at the conference room at exactly 2:00 PM for a very important meeting"
  }
]
```

Comment: One thing, the button event listener in the buttons works fine, but when I move the Toast into the response closure, it doesn't fire.

Comment: its possible that onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) is calling. have you debug that?

Comment: @aksacha Yes, Not message is printed in the printStack

Comment: i dont get it.. is message printing or not?

Comment: use JsonRequest instead of stringRequest for GET request.

Comment: Something strange is rather happening. I realized that if I surround the code in a try catch statement, code under that catch part will produce the json instead.

Comment: Don't Toast. Use `Log` instead

Comment: @cricket_007 The issue is that which method I use, e.getMessage() under the catch block is the one giving my json instead of jsonObject.toString() in the try block.

Comment: Your exception can't give you the proper JSON string, otherwise, you wouldn't have an exception. So again, Log instead of Toast, and check the logcat against the response you expected. Also, please put your logcat in your question when you do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[
   {
```

You have an array of objects, not one object.

Your exception likely says it expected a { character, but got a [. For example,

> org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

So, you want `new JSONArray(response)`

Or use Volleys JSONArrayRequest

Comment: This is the message from the Logcat when I log error in the catch block. D/Feedback: Value [{"id":"1","body":"Hello to all staff of Holy Trinity Medical Center, We welcome you all to 2017. Wishing you all a properous New year","date_created":"2017-02-17 11:04:12","title":"Welcome to 2017"},{"id":"2","body":"All National Service Persons are expected to meet at the conference room at exactly 2:00 PM for a very important meeting","date_created":"2017-02-17 11:15:50","title":"Special Announcement"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: `org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`... And you don't understand this, why?

Comment: I bow down my head in shame. I didn't see the latter part of the message.

Comment: Like I said ;) Don't Toast an exception

Comment: Thanks! I now understands the difference between JSONObject and JSONArray.